# Configuring ASP.NET to run under IIS in Windows 7

Tags: asp.net, iis

How do I configure an ASP.NET application to run under IIS in windows 7? I am using Visual Studio 2010 and when I run my web app I am getting an error message that you do not have permission to access the web server.

Comment: Did you set this up in a directory outside inetpub\wwwroot? If you do that sometimes you need to set up the IIS users to have access to that folder.

Answer (score 1):

you have a couple of options.

1) copy the files to your inetpub\wwwroot folder then open iis manager and create an application in the Default Web Site of the folder you just created.

2) in Visual Studio, you can publish

3) in Visual Studio, you could open the properties page of the web application, click on the web tab and in there, an option for creating the virtual directory exists. Press it - it creates the virtual directory and you can then run the website using that url. VS will automatically launch the site pointing to IIS when you run the app

remember, be sure you are running in Administrator mode (if using UAC).

one more thing - be sure you have installed IIS (Programs and features > Internet Information Services)